# Problems with the method ecdsa.VerifyData()

Tags: c#, xunit, private-key, public-key, ecdsa

I'm trying to verify some data with a public key the method ecdsa.VerifyData() that I'm signing with private key and I'm getting a false return and I don't know why.

These are the methods to Sign and Verify the data:

```
        public byte[] SignData(byte[] dataValue)
        {
            X509Certificate2 privateKey = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyPfxFile);

            //Encryting/Signing a hash
            using (ECDsa ecdsa = privateKey.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
            {
                if (ecdsa == null) throw new Exception("Not an ECDSA cert, or has no private key");

                return ecdsa.SignData(dataValue, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            }
        }
        public bool VerifyData(byte[] dataValue, byte[] dataSigned)
        {
            byte[] mycertCer = Properties.Resources.mycertCer;
            X509Certificate2 publicKey = new X509Certificate2(mycertCer);

            //Checking the hash and signature
            using (ECDsa ecdsa = publicKey.GetECDsaPublicKey())
            {
                if (ecdsa == null) throw new Exception("Not an ECDSA cert, or has no private key");

                return ecdsa.VerifyData(dataValue, dataSigned, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            }
        }
```

This is how I create the keys:

```
        public void CreateAsymmetricKeysPair(string path, string keyName)
        {
            var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair
            var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=localhost", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));

            // Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Join(path, keyName + ".pfx"), cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));

            // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Join(path,keyName + ".cer"),
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" 
                + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
                + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
        }
```

That is my unit test that I'm getting a false return:

```
        private const string rawText = "test";

        [Fact]
        public void OnSignData_DoReturnSignature_WhenValidStream()
        {
            //Arrange
            var rawBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawText);

            //Act
            var signature = licenseService.SignData(rawBytes);
            var isValid = licenseService.VerifyData(rawBytes, signature);

            //Assert
            Assert.True(isValid);
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This might be useful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50445252/9929694

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my computer. I have loaded the .pfx and .cer file from the file system. Check if in your environment both files belong together and the consistency of the rest of the data.

Comment: @Topaco, so you mean that this code worked well in your environment, is it?

Comment: @HenryMigo, I'm reading this to see if I can get anything from here, tks.

Comment: Yeah it does seem like Topaco is saying that it works for him.

Comment: Thank you @HenryMigo, I will check my environment and test with the keys in my file system.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that this line was returning my old public key even that I deleted and pasted another one.

```
byte[] mycertCer = Properties.Resources.mycertCer;
```